# Primitive.ObjectID to string in Golang

Tags: string, mongodb, go, objectid, mongo-go

I am trying to convert type `primitive.ObjectID` to `string` type in Go. I am using `mongo-driver` from `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver`.

I tried using type assertion like-

```
mongoId := mongoDoc["_id"];
stringObjectID := mongoId.(string)
```

Which VSCode accepts. Code gets compiled and when it reaches this specific line of code, it throws this error

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is primitive.ObjectID, not string
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell you how to convert `primitive.ObjectID` to a string if you don't tell us how `primitive.ObjectID` is defined.

Comment: hi Flimzy, 
It was defined like this
var parentOrder bson.M;
and appened into slice array, and the slice array was defined like this
var mapArray []bson.M

Function loops through this slice array to scan _id like I explained above. 
mongoDoc is one single mongo document of type bson.M

Comment: Please update the question with that information.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error message tells `mongoDoc["_id"]` is of type `interface{}` which holds a value of type [`primitive.ObjectID`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID). This is not a `string`, it's a distinct type. You can only type assert `primitive.ObjectID` from the interface value.

If you want a `string` representation of this MongoDB ObjectId, you may use its [`ObjectID.Hex()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID.Hex) method to get the hex representation of the ObjectId's bytes:

```
mongoId := mongoDoc["_id"]
stringObjectID := mongoId.(primitive.ObjectID).Hex()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my life. It worked like magic. Thanks again

Comment: how to convert a string to object ID?

Comment: nowadays you can just do mongoId.Hex()

Comment: @bashizip Yes, that's what the answer says. If you have an `ObjectID`, you may call its `Hex()` method. The type assertion is needed if you have the document in a map with `interface{}` value type.

Comment: @icza thank you for the precision, I'm still new to golang and I just learn something from you

Answer (score 5):

nowadays you can just do mongoId.Hex()

Answer (score 4):

Things have changed in 2021. Here is a more easy way. It takes the user from models asking what kind of type it is from interface then all good

```
var user models.User

query := bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{{"username": data["username"]}, {"email": data["username"]}}}

todoCollection := config.MI.DB.Collection(os.Getenv("DATABASE_COLLECTION_USER"))
todoCollection.FindOne(c.Context(), query).Decode(&user)

stringObjectID := user.ObjectID.Hex()
```

Above code works with this interface:

```
type User struct {
    ObjectID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"_id"`

    // Id        string    `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    Username      string    `json:"username" gorm:"unique" bson:"username,omitempty"`
    Email         string    `json:"email" gorm:"unique" bson:"email,omitempty"`
    Password      []byte    `json:"password" bson:"password"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `json:"createdat" bson:"createat"`
    DeactivatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedat" bson:"updatedat"`
}
```

So consequently: this 3 line codes would do it nicely:

```
objectidhere := primitive.NewObjectID()
stringObjectID := objectidhere.Hex()

filename_last := filename_rep + "_" + stringObjectID + "." + fileExt
```

Comment: for bongo package in go use code userModel.DocumentBase.GetId().Hex()

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringObjectId string = mongoId.(primitive.ObjectID).String()
```