# String to Primitive.ObjectID

Tags: go, objectid, mongo-go

I am using mongo-driver from go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver. I already converted **primitive.ObjectID to string**
Using this link [Primitive.ObjectID to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864873/primitive-objectid-to-string)

Now i need to convert **string to primitive.ObjectID**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60865164/4966953) uses [ObjectID.Hex()](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID.Hex) to obtain a string of the hexadecimal representation of the ObjectID.

The very same API docs have a [ObjectIDFromHex](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectIDFromHex) function to do the reverse:

```
func ObjectIDFromHex(s string) (ObjectID, error)
```

Use it as follows:

```golang
objID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(hexString)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

**Quick reminder**: always read the docs of the libraries you are using.