# How to convert String to Primitive.ObjectID in Golang?

Tags: string, go, casting, type-conversion, primitive

There are questions similar to this. But mostly they are using Hex()(like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864873/primitive-objectid-to-string-in-golang/60865164)) for primitive Object to String conversion. I'm using String() for conversion. How do I convert it back to primitive Object type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String()` method of types may result in an arbitrary string representation. Parsing it may not always be possible, as it may not contain all the information the original value holds, or it may not be "rendered" in a  way that is parsable unambiguously. There's also no guarantee the "output" of `String()` doesn't change over time.

Current implementation of [`ObjectID.String()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.2/bson/primitive#ObjectID.String) does this:

```
func (id ObjectID) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("ObjectID(%q)", id.Hex())
}
```

Which results in a string like this:

```
ObjectID("4af9f070cc10e263c8df915d")
```

This is parsable, you just have to take the hex number, and pass it to [`primitive.ObjectIDFromHex()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.2/bson/primitive#ObjectIDFromHex):

For example:

```
id := primitive.NewObjectID()
s := id.String()
fmt.Println(s)

hex := s[10:34]
id2, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(hex)
fmt.Println(id2, err)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/QatvGhVwOoZ)):

```
ObjectID("4af9f070cc10e263c8df915d")
ObjectID("4af9f070cc10e263c8df915d") <nil>
```

This solution could be improved to find `"` characters in the string representation and use the indices instead of the fixed `10` and `34`, but you shouldn't be transferring and parsing the result of `ObjectID.String()` in the first place. You should use its [`ObjectID.Hex()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.2/bson/primitive#ObjectID.Hex) method in the first place, which can be passed as-is to `primitive.ObjectIDFromHex()`.